# Re- Wire a DAC for newer GPIO pin layout

Tags: rpi.gpio, hifiberry

I have a Hifiberry DAC for a model B and would like to use it on b+ or pi 2. I know the GPIO pins have changed from model B layout - would it be possible to figure out the old and new layout differences and wire the DAC to the new pi this way?

The P5 header doesn't seem to exist anymore, although it seems the first 26pins remain the same. As far as a gather the P5 header was used to transfer the audio data from the board to the DAC. So if I can find which pins replace these would it be a simple case of rewiring these pins or is there a fundamental difference here I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The P5 header has the following pins supporting PCM (high quality audio).

```
P5-03 GPIO28 PCM_CLK
P5-04 GPIO29 PCM_FS
P5-05 GPIO30 PCM_DIN
P5-06 GPIO31 PCM_DOUT
(All set to mode ALT2)
```

Those gpios are not available on the A+/B+/Pi2

The A+/B+/Pi2 have the following pins supporting PCM.

```
Pin 12 GPIO18 PCM_CLK
Pin 35 GPIO19 PCM_FS
Pin 38 GPIO20 PCM_DIN
Pin 40 GPIO21 PCM_DOUT
(All set to mode ALT0)
```

You could certainly wire the Hifiberry to the new pins.  You could also set the gpios to be in mode ALT0 so that they transmit PCM.

The question is would your Hifiberry driver work on the A+/B+/Pi2.  I don't know.